# Is it possible to force-install an extension on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

The way it is on [Linux](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start) and [Windows](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/windows-quick-start)?

Note this is a private Chromebook, not a *Google for Work* or *Education* one.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to force install Chrome extensions for private Chromebook. But, if you use for work or education, force-installing an extension can be done via group policy or master_preferences. For more information regarding Chroem extension policy check this: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en

Comment: Thank you @d.datul1990, I'll keep the question open to see if anyone has any creative idea...

Comment: ok. no worries mate :)

Comment: Just FYI, Google thought that this is the way of hacking user's Chromebook. they keep removing the way of installation without notification.

Comment: Thanks @SunggukLim. My use case is a public chromebook where I want to allow only certain websites. No ulterior motive here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome OS does not allow policy management locally since you don't have access to the profile or filesystem (like you do in Linux and Windows).  you need to get a domain and enroll your device in it, and then manage the device via the admin console.

you can load extensions unpacked like any other OS -- unzip it into your Downloads directory, then go into the extensions page, check the developer mode box, then use the load unpacked extension button.  a pita, but it works.